# How to assign a value to a name in a spreadsheet (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to give a particular name, such as Math_class1, a corresponding value such that when I list various of them in a column that I see their correct names and at the bottom the sum of their values and be able to easily move names around and have the sums quickly change.

This is how I want it to look.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want. Where is `Math_class1` in that screenshot supposed to be? By a "corresponding value" you mean a numerical one?

Comment: Math_class1 was an example. And yes I mean to give each name a numeric value.

Comment: Oh, ok. So you mean that each value shown in column `B` in that screenshot has a numerical value assigned to it? E.g. `CSP = 5`, `EECS = 7` and so on?

Comment: That's what I want yes. And so that if I change the name it automatically sums up the newly placed classes.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this with two sheets.

## Sheet 2

Create a second sheet (`Sheet2`) where numerical values are assigned to each string (subject?), as in:

| Subject (Column A) | Credits (Column B) |
| --- | --- |
| CSP | 5 |
| BOOKS | 7 |
| EECS | 3 |
| Math_class1 | 5 |
| Physics | 4 |
| UC | 3 |

## Sheet 1

Then, back to `Sheet1` (the main sheet).

I use the same structure as in your screenshot, meaning that all relevant subjects are in column `B`.

Add the following to column `C2` and hide it with white color:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!$A:$A, Sheet2!$B:$B), 0)
```

(and analogously for `C3`, `C4` etc.)

You will then get the total results with:

`=SUM(C:C)`.

## Example

[See the example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zt2kDHPcV388C93Ossi_4phDxTbmyjvTyld2VJwoTFo/edit?usp=sharing).